# Issue to output mysql result

Tags: php, mysql

I create a form to register company and insert into DB. also created a form to insert each company cost and sell price. after all this has been inserted in DB, i try to output it on table but it was showing the company id instead of name... please bellow illustrate better

***company*** DB

```
|id | company_name |
|1  | Oliva Ltd    |
|2  | Bone Mill    |
```

***comp_product*** DB

```
|id | company_id   | cp     | sp    |
|3  | 2            | 20000  | 18000 |
|4  | 1            | 3000   | 100   |
```

The help I need is to output all data from comp_product DB by representing the `company_id` with their `company_name` from company DB.

Ouput Table

```
| company_id   | cp     | sp    |
| Bone Mill    | 20000  | 18000 |
| Oliva Ltd    | 3000   | 100   |
```

i tried bellow code, but i was showing only one row.

```
<table>
                          <thead>
                          <tr>
                              <th>company_id</th>
                              <th>cp</th>
                              <th>sp</th>
                          </tr>
                          <?php 

                          $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comp_product ORDER BY id DESC");
                                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                                {
                                    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM company WHERE id ='".$row['company_id']."'");
                                            while($rowz = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                                                { $name = $rowz['company_name']; }
                                    ?>
                          <tr>
                              <td><?php echo $name ?></td>
                              <td><?php echo $row['cp'] ?></td>
                              <td><?php echo $row['cp'] ?></td>
                          </tr>
                          <?php 
                                }
                                ?>
                      </table>
```

Show can I do this. Thanks for understanding

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says [your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: ok.. thanks for the advise.... how can i use PDO to determine the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a JOIN query

```
SELECT `company`.`company_name`, `comp_product`.`cp`, `comp_product`.`sp`
FROM `company`
LEFT JOIN `comp_cp`
ON `company`.`id` = `comp_product`.`company_id`
```

***You do not need two queries***, you can just loop through the results of one. If you need to limit this to one company you can add a `WHERE` clause.

---

In addition you need to [stop using `mysql_*` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Thanks... can I also JOIN query in PDO to get the result, moving to PDO now

Comment: I have started with PDO, it works but joining the query, but i added a company to company DB only making it 3 data... but I still have 2 data in comp_product DB. problem is that it show all the 3 data and set to a blank the third line...

Comment: You may want to post a new question for that @sammyltk, showing your new code, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 "SELECT company.company_name as company_id,comp_product.cp 
 ,comp_product.sp  FROM company inner join comp_product on 
 company.id = comp_product.company_id
 ORDER BY company.id DESC"
```

You will get desired result .

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this query to properly show the data:

```
mysql_query ("SELECT company.company_name as company_id,comp_product.cp 
 ,comp_product.sp  FROM company where 
 company.id = comp_product.company_id
 ORDER BY company.id DESC");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code outputting one row is simply because you're reusing the `$result` variable for both queries.

The name query result overwrites the price query.

Your code looks like this right now:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comp_product ORDER BY id DESC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM company WHERE id ='".$row['company_id']."'");
    while($rowz = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 

      $name = $rowz['company_name']; 
}
```

Change it to:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comp_product ORDER BY id DESC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    $name_query_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM company WHERE id ='".$row['company_id']."'");
    while($rowz = mysql_fetch_array($name_query_result)){ 

      $name = $rowz['company_name']; 
}
```